# What is the correct way to use soyutils with Google Closure?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library, google-closure-templates

I am trying to use [Google Closure templates (Soy)](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/) with [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/).

I am including the `soyutils_usegoog.js` utilities file as instructed. This file provides a number of utilities used by the generated templates, notably `soy.StringBuilder`. Here's how it is creating it:

```
soy.StringBuilder = goog.string.StringBuffer;
```

The soyutils file requires `goog.string.StringBuffer` a few lines above, but when running in non-compiled mode this results in a runtime error because the JS file that `StringBuffer` resides in will not be loaded until *after* soyutils has executed.

Unless I am mistaken, JS files in Closure should not immediately access namespaces that they 'require'. The `<script>` tag is only added after the execution of the current script (in non-compiled mode) so immediate usage will result in a runtime error.

In short, how can I load in `soyutils_usegoog.js` without triggering a runtime error due to the early access of `good.string.StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you recreating deps.js with your compiled templates as an input (and `soyutils_usegoog.js`)? And then are you `goog.require`-ing your template? Something like this should work:

```
<script src="/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script src="/closure-library/closure/goog/deps.js"></script><!-- might not need this line if base.js is setup to auto include deps.js -->
<script>
    goog.require('your.template');//this will pull in and execute all the dependencies (including StringBuffer) for your template
</script>
<script>
    alert(your.template());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the question has been asked on http://groups.google.com/group/closure-templates-discuss?